# How to access secure Azure web api using adal and Angular 5

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-web-api, angular5, adal

I have a simple test web API deployed as an app on our Azure tenancy.  The single web service method is set as authorized.

I have also created two client apps.  The **first uses Angular JS** and adal.js and adal-angular.js.  This application uses Azure AD to authenticate, and it **successfully** accesses the test method on the Azure deployed api.

The **second application is built with Angular 5 and uses the adal-angular5** npm library.  It does authenticate against our Azure AD, but it will not get to the test method.  Using the supplied example code on the npm page, it will not even place the http get (no xhr request shows up in Chrome network tab).  No error shows up in the console, but an "invalid_state" error appears in the Application Session Storage.

One interesting note is that in the AngularJS app, the id token and the access token appear to be different, and the access token works with a Postman request.  The id and access tokens in the adal-angular5 version are the same, and do not perform the get in Postman ("message": "Authorization has been denied for this request.")

**Has anyone successfully used adal-angular5 to authenticate an Azure web api?**

Or, is anyone aware of a mechanism that DOES work with Angular 5 and an Azure web api?

Either way, sample code would be awesome!

I'd be most grateful for any help on this.

Comment: Interesting :) We've got a similar set up. Are you using Azure AD B2C?

And why aren't you using the Microsoft library MSAL JS?

Comment: We are not using Azure AD B2C, but we will try that out.  Thanks!